# how do i check the result is between two numbers?

Tags: c#

I have read the second line in a text file which contains `2.75` and I am trying to get it to do something if it meets certain criteria. I'm sure I have done this before and has a simple answer but I can't seen to figure it out.

```
string SecondLine;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(SPFile2))
{
    reader.ReadLine();
    SecondLine = reader.ReadLine();
}
int NewValue;
NewValue = Convert.ToInt32(SecondLine);
if ((NewValue >= 2) && (NewValue <= 2.99))
{
    // Do Something
}
if ((NewValue >= 3) && (NewValue <= 3.99))
{
    // Do something else
}
```

What have I missed out?

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert `2.75` to `Int32`?

Comment: @Alfie, coercion to `int` truncates towards zero.

Comment: am I supposed to use double somehow?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that seems stupid, but thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @SeanProbyn well... yes, that's the logical solution to holding a number which has decimal points

Comment: The question is not what you're supposed to do, but what you want to achieve. Given that you intend to compare the number to non-integer ones, you are better of with `float`/`double`/`decimal`.

Comment: This is quite simple, put a breakpoint after conversion to int. If you have an unexpected result, then there is a formatting issue with the string. Otherwise it's working as it supposed to do it :)

Comment: If you are trying to check if the number is between 2 and 3, you will also have a problem if your number is something like 2.996. It won't fall in to any of your `if` statements.

Comment: it will only ever be 2 decimal place

Comment: it says  Input string was not in a correct format but I know the answer in it is 2.75

Comment: try using a `decimal` and `decimal.Parse` instead of `Convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a decimal number to an `Int32` that does not hold decimals. This will turn the number in `NewValue` into `2` as it truncates towards zero. You need to store the variable in a `double`, `float` or `decimal` whichever is best for your requirements.

See the following example that uses a `double` and [`Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double newValue = Double.Parse(secondLine);
```

Note that if you are unsure if the value will be a double you should use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
double newValue;
bool result = Double.TryParse(secondLine, out newValue);
if (!result) //Parse failed
```

Note that if the parsing fails it may be down to your culture settings i.e. a ',' for the decimal separator not a '.'. However there is an overload for `Parse` and `TryParse` that allows you to pass culture information in.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this double and double.parse its kind of new but thanks for the help that has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a string that represents a double into a integer
that will cause a

> System.IFormatException
>
> {"Input string was not in a correct
>   format."}{"Input string was not in a correct format."}

if you know it is a number with decimal part then do:

```
var newValue = Convert.ToDouble(secondLine);
```

if you know it is an integer then try:

```
var newValue = Convert.ToInt32(secondLine);
```